# How do I set up a bash alias for a common working folder?

Tags: bash, function, alias

I want to set up a bash alias or function (let's call it "myfolder") to a common working directory (let's call it `~/some/deep/working/folder`) and I want to be able to call it like this:

`cd myfolder/bob` to access the child folder "bob".

If I use `alias myfolder='~/some/deep/working/folder'`, I can use `cd myfolder`, but I can't use `cd myfolder/bob`.

How do I get the alias expansion to happen first, and then have any other text be added onto the command before executing the command?

Comment: Why not use a symlink?

Comment: @Kevin I would like to be able to use it in any directory that I'm currently in, not just from my home directory.

Comment: Did you actually try your `cd myfolder` idea? Aliases are not expanded in non-command position.

Comment: @chepner I used it for a few months like that.  I use zsh for my shell, so maybe that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two workarounds:

Add this to your .bashrc:

```
CDPATH="$CDPATH:$HOME/some/deep/working"
```

then you can use

```
cd folder/bob
```

from everywhere.

---

Use a variable:

```
myfolder="$HOME/some/deep/working/folder"
cd "$myfolder/bob"
```